# call webbrowser control on code behind of asp.net page error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

How do you use a webbrowser control in code behind of a asp.net page. I get this error:

ActiveX control cannot be instantiated because the current thread is not in a single-threaded apartment.

thanks for the help

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls

Partial Class _Default

    Dim testcontrol As New WebBrowser() ' it breaks here

    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        testcontrol.Navigate("mysite")

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: why is Page_Load not public? the main site is another file, so to catch the propagated event (Page_Load) the handler needs to be public.

Comment: its not public because that how it gets added automatically

Comment: hmm makes sense. are you sure you do not need to overload WebBrowser?

Comment: ya im sure - it works in a win forms app - just dont know why it wont work in a asp.net app

Comment: is the Webbrowser not already defined as `HTTP_USERAGENT` or sth along these lines?

Comment: i dont know...... i see that in a console app sth attribute needs to be added

Comment: Can you explain more about what you are trying to achieve, I can think of very few reasons why you would want to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to use WebBrowser behind the scenes in a ASP.NET app? If you need to interact with a web page on another server, usually people do that using `HttpWebRequest`.

Somebody out there can correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe a web app, almost by definition, cannot be single-threaded.  Web apps are meant to be multi-user, to be doing multiple things and accommodating multiple users at once.

Comment: hi  - thanks for the reply - what I'm trying to do is to take a screen shot of another page without loading it. In a windows forms and a windows console app I can do it , surly this must be possible in a web app?

Comment: @Hello-World  By "screen shot", do you mean creating an image of how the page would appear?  Or doing a scrape of that page's HTML?  Is the page on the same domain as your app or completely different?

Comment: I'm trying to get am image of another page on an intranet but it is on several different domains

Answer (score 0):

This is working:

```
/// <summary>
        /// Returns a thumbnail for the current member values
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Thumbnail bitmap</returns>
        protected Bitmap GetThumbnail()
        {
            try
            {
            // WebBrowser is an ActiveX control that must be run in a single-threaded
            // apartment so create a thread to create the control and generate the
            // thumbnail
            Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(GetThumbnailWorker));
            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            thread.Start();
            thread.Join();
            return _bmp;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("log.txt", true))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(string.Format("[{0}] {1}", DateTime.Now.ToString(), ex.ToString()));
                    writer.Flush();
                    writer.Close();
                }
                return null;
            }
        }


/// <summary>
        /// Creates a WebBrowser control to generate the thumbnail image
        /// Must be called from a single-threaded apartment
        /// </summary>
        protected void GetThumbnailWorker()
        {
            try
            {
                using (WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser())
                {
                    browser.ClientSize = new Size(_width, _height);
                    //browser.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
                    browser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
                    browser.Navigate(_url);
                    // Wait for control to load page
                    while (browser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
                        Application.DoEvents();
                    // Render browser content to bitmap
                    _bmp = new Bitmap(_thumbWidth, _thumbHeight);
                    browser.DrawToBitmap(_bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, _thumbWidth, _thumbHeight));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("log.txt", true))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(string.Format("[{0}] {1}", DateTime.Now.ToString(), ex.ToString()));
                    writer.Flush();
                    writer.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```